# counting map pins

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

i have a map application that inserts map pins when the user moves to certain locations, my question is how do i count the number of times the user has passed or has been on that same place.

Has in the following example:

User has been on place A with (latitude, longitude) five times.

Here is the code i have so far:

> ```
> [outletMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
>                     [outletMapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
>                     [outletMapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
>
>                     MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
>                     region.center.latitude = [[eachObject objectForKey:@"latitudeFrom"] floatValue];
>                     //NSLog(@"latitudeFrom=%f",[[eachObject objectForKey:@"latitudeFrom"] floatValue]);
>                     region.center.longitude = [[eachObject objectForKey:@"longitudeFrom"] floatValue];
>                     //NSLog(@"longitudeFrom=%f",[[eachObject objectForKey:@"longitudeFrom"] floatValue]);
>                     region.span.longitudeDelta = 6;
>                     region.span.latitudeDelta = 7;
>                     [outletMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
>                     /////
>                     float longitude = [[eachObject objectForKey:@"latitudeFrom"] floatValue];
>                     float latitude = [[eachObject objectForKey:@"longitudeFrom"] floatValue];
>
>                     CLLocationCoordinate2D locationco = {latitude,longitude};
>
>                     ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
>                     ann.coordinate = locationco;
>                     ann.title = [eachObject objectForKey:@"setDepartureAirportOrCode"];
>
>                     int count=0;
>                     for(int j = aux; j < [objects count]; j++){
>                         for(int k = j+1;k < [objects count]-j;k++){
>                             NSMutableDictionary *item1 = [objects objectAtIndex:j];
>                             NSMutableDictionary *item2 = [objects objectAtIndex:k];
>
>                             NSString *str1 = [item1 valueForKey:@"setDepartureAirportOrCode"];
>                             NSString *str2 = [item2 valueForKey:@"setDepartureAirportOrCode"];
>                            // NSLog(@"%@==%@ ???",str1,str2);
>                             if([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
>                                  NSLog(@"%@==%@ MATCH!!!",str1,str2);
>                                 count++;
>                         }
>                     }
>
>
>
>                     /* Contagem */
>
>                     ann.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
>                     ann.coordinate = region.center;
>                     [outletMapView addAnnotation:ann];
> ```

Sorry for my poor english, please dont down rate, any question or doubt just aks me im always online.

Comment: Isnt [objects count] then amount of pins you have?

Comment: yes i have the total amount of pins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a region around each pin and tell the cllocationmanager to tell you when the device gets close.

```
CLLocationAccuracy acc = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
[self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:aRegion desiredAccuracy:acc];
```

When you get a callback (the delegate method `didEnterRegion`) you can increment a counter

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
   NSLog(@"GeoFence: didEnterRegion");    
}
```

I'll leave it to you to work out which counter you need to increment for each region

Answer (score 0):

You already have the number of pins using [objects count].

Comment: But the question was to count the number of times the user has been to a place, not how many pins they have.